# ggplot2 - common color scale across multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale

I have two dataset with different min and max values, see 'z' in the dataframes df1 and df2.

Question: How do I define the colors for both datasets so the resulting plots, i.e. their colorbar scales make sense?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), 2),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = c(0.00e+00,4.56e-03,3.93e-04,4.89e-05,1.63e-02,
        2.59e-02,1.06e-02,-2.87e-04,-3.28e-03,-4.90e-04)
)
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey50")

df2 <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), 2),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = c(0.00e+00,-2.94e+00,9.64e-01,8.00e-01,-1.29e-05,
        0.00e+00,-3.65e-04,8.09e+00,-2.94e-03,-9.75e-01)
)
ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey50")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can add `scale_fill_gradient(limits = range(df1$z, df2$z))` to both charts in order to impose the same range for each. Do note that in your example, `df1$z`'s actual range is much smaller than that of `df2$z`, so its chart would essentially show a uniform shade of blue afterwards. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I need them to be on the same scale, it's sensitivity analysis.  Thansk for the advice, it worked! 
Another thing I need to solve is that when combining these plots e.g. with `grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 2)` two color bars appear while one would be better, idas?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008413/ggplot2-match-plot-area-height-of-combined-plots) using `library(ggpubr)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying same limits for colorbar (legend) in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314251/specifying-same-limits-for-colorbar-legend-in-ggplot2)